# Data stored on variable only one/first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller where I get some data to be updated on my page, but I'm having some kind of issue with the data that is injected in my controller.

Basically the data that is injected in my controller keeps updated always in real time, but I need the first data loaded in the page be saved in a variable and not be changed, but for some reason it keeps being updated.

My code:

```
vm.storedData = null;

function activate() { 
    if(vm.storedData == null){
        vm.storedData = data.condition_lines;
    }
}

activate();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The reason is quite simple, when you do "=" in code e.g. vm.storedData = data.condition_lines; you create a new variable that is basically just a pointer to a "data.contidion_lines", so any changes to data.condition_lines will reflect in vm.storedData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is caused by the way Javascript stores objects.

`data` is an object. `data` doesn't store condition_lines, it stores a reference to condition_lines, so setting `vm.storedData = data.condition_lines;`, causes assignment by reference. As a result, vm.storedData will ALWAYS equal data.condition_lines.

You could use angular.copy() to effectively assign by value instead (it does more complex stuff under the hood, but the results are the same).

`vm.storedData = angular.copy(data.condition_lines);`

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have pointed a reference variable (vm.storedData) at another object, so since the value of data.condition_lines is still changing, so is the the storedData.

If you copy the contents of the condition_lines across to the storedData, you should get what you want.

You might want this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy